# Find specific button in a button array (swift)

Tags: swift

I have a button array. when i have a sender, how can i match the sender with the button inside the array?

```
for var i in 0...index.count{
if(button == sender)
index = i
}
```

Can i loop through the array and find the specific button like this?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and check if the button and the sender are the same

```
for button in buttonArray {
    if button == sender {
        //that's the button
    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder that how can they match each other. depends on what??

Comment: UIButton conforms to NSObject and NSObject conforms to equatable. I don't know what exactly is compared and I can't find anything online but I know that the comparison is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to find index of `sender` in array (since you already have button object itself, it is `sender`), just do this:

```
if let index = buttonArray.indexOf(sender) {
    // do smthng
}
```